# How can I take over the space ship "Fortuna" from Marco Graziani?

Tags: starfield

In a quest I have an encounter with Marco Graziani. His ship is a huge flying museum and full of decorations, wild plants and expensive wines.

How is it possible to get to the pilot seat and take ownership of his "Fortuna"?

(From outside, you can jump to the roof of the "Fortuna" and see the pilot seat and a airlock door).

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you can't. It isn't actually a ship (internally to the game), it's a location.

It's a shame really because it's a rather nice ship too.